# Encode a series of Images into a MediaStream in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, webrtc

I have multiple NodeJS peers capturing series of images. Sometimes they are required to send data through [WebRTC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc) to some browser peers.

I'm currently handling the problem by Base64 encoding the images, sending them through DataChannel and rapidly (about 20-30 fps) displaying them on a `<img>` tag. But it seems a bit messy, is there a way to take these series of images and encode them into a `MediaStream` so that I can take advantage of the native support on some browsers?

- I know `node-webrtc` currently don't support `MediaStream`, I need to analyze how hard would it be to build it. But first I have to know if there is a way to do this in the first place.
- This application must transmit this data only by WebRTC - as it is handling the [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) between the peers.

Comment: _20-30 fps_ is video. You'd rather use existing technologies instead of reinventing the wheel with _displaying images rapidly_ :) You need to encode a valid video stream of your images. Displaying images is not a realtime process in browsers. You will never achieve same smoothness and sync as with video

Comment: But even if I encode a valid video stream, would I be able to transmit it via WebRTC from a NodeJS application to a browser and display it? A video stream would be worth nothing if I couldn't display it.

Comment: Simple googling https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc

Comment: Yes, i mentioned it on my question: "I know node-webrtc...". But it does not handle `MediaStream`. and it does not convert a series of images on a `MediaStream` - so it's not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using web sockets in node js for media streaming server

Try http://binaryjs.com/

Server Code

```
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
server.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(meta.file);
    stream.pipe(file);
  }); 
});
```

Client Code

```
var client = BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
client.on('open', function(stream){
  var stream = client.createStream({file: 'hello.txt'});
  stream.write('Hello');
  stream.write('World!');
  stream.end();
});
```

Comment: Using web sockets wouldn't be an option on my case. I have multiple NodeJS peer applications united by a central server that just handle the signalling. I'm using WebRTC to handle the UDP hole punching between the peers.